# Custom "Global Actions" are not appearing in salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-platform, global-actions

I have created some custom "Global actions" in Salesforce Ligtning, plus drag drop these actions in my new Publisher layout and assigned this layout to the Admin & User profile.

But when I see the Global Action after this operation, its only showing standard Global Action and hiding all the custom actions.

What can I do to achieve the requirement of showing custom actions in "Global Action"...?

Answer (score 1):

As per the Spring '17 release notes topic [Take More Actions from the Global Actions Menu](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_general_lex_global_action_menu_enhanced.htm), it's now possible to add custom actions to the global layout in Lightning.

I verified that not only are global Create a Record quick actions showing up in the global actions menu, but so are Lightning Component quick actions.

Answer (score 0):

Custom global actions are not yet supported in the lightning experience .Vote  an idea on idea exchange for this.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000LjJsAAK

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohith Shrivastava,
I got to know this it works on salesforce1, not on desktop.
But I am still searching to make it possible anyhow, so is there any way to make it work or create your own global actions links via Code/Metadata Update or Configuration?!